# TIBCO Business Connect not starting up

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-businessconnect

I have just installed the TIBCO BusinessConnect 6.2 on my machine after installing TRA 5.9. 
After installation, when I try to start the BCEngine, it is failing always with the error as below. Can someone who had faced this earlier guide me as to what the reason could be for this.

> Error [BW-Core] BWENGINE-100001 com/tibco/bw/store/RepoAgentjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tibco/bw/store/RepoAgentat com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.do(Unknown Source)at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.a(Unknown Source)at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.(Unknown Source)at com.tibco.pe.PEMain.main(Unknown Source)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.bw.store.RepoAgentat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)... 5 more

I have tried reinstalling, changing the domain properties to have a different database store. Nothing worked. Additionally, I am not even able to add Business Connect to Administrator even after browsing the admin-plugin as well.

Anyone who had come across this?

Comment: What is the `BW` version? Also can you list the files from directory path `tibco/bw/<your version>/lib/palettes`?